# Finding the Z value from the tail area of a distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

[image]

Hi everyone. I'm really struggling with **question v)**. I can't look up 0.99...

Here are the answers I have so far:

```
i) 1.64
ii) -1.64
iii) 2.05
iv) -2.12
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/z_table.html

Comment: For v), I expect the reason you can't  look up who has $0.99$ to its right is that your table is only for positive values of $z$. So look up who has $0.01$ to its right, and change the sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers look fine

The last is about $-2.326348$.